# New object referencing to an old object

Tags: java, reference

I have a simple Java program like this

```
public Class MyObject {
    List<anotherObject> anotherObjectList;
    int average;
}
```

and a method in my main class

```
List<MyObject> getIdealList(List<MyObject> myObjectList){
    List<MyObject> idealList = new Arraylist<>(myObjectList);
    for(int i = 0; i< myObjectList.size() ; i++)
    {
        myObjectList = makeSomeChangesInEachAnotherObjectList(myObjectList)
        if(isMyObjectListIdeal(myObjectList))
        {
             idealList = new Arraylist<>(myObjectList);
        }    
    }
    return idealList;
}
```

So the myObjectList is constantly changed until the anotherObjectList has the ideal formation. Logically this seems correct, but even when isMyObjectListIdeal() is false, when I change the formation of myObjectList in makeSomeChangesInEachAnotherObjectList, the idealist also seems to change it's value

Is there a reason why both idealist and myObjectList points to the same anotherObjectList? Is there a solution for this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What exact code for functions makeSomeChangesInEachAnotherObjectList(myObjectList) and isMyObjectListIdeal(myObjectList), You might be changing the values of object in "myObjectList" and return the new list with same object. in this case return and passed list both have update data. like wise isMyObjectListIdeal(myObjectList) function would be doing.

Comment: @Amin " so any change in each of list, reflect both of them because object are same only in different container."   It is not true , The changes does not reflect

Comment: @Tarun I mean "idealList" is not deep copy of "myObjectList" so if we send "myObjectList" to another method and change its values (change list values directly not replace them with new object), this values changed in "idealList" (both reference to same place) as far as I know. Is it not correct? Did I make a mistake?

Comment: @Amin Yes you are not correct , Suggest you tto produce scenario and try it yourself to get it clear

Comment: @Tarun creating a new list wit: _new Arraylist<>(myObjectList);_ does NOT make a deep copy that's what Amin put in his words. And he is right about this

Comment: @Tarun. I doesn't work until now with chat room but can you come in this room: "Ask about problem" I think that I didn't understand what you said.

Comment: @star67  I am not saying about deep copy or something else, only this  _"so any change in each of list, reflect both of them because object are same only in different container."_ is not true

Comment: @Tarun he put in his words _"any change in each of list, reflect both of them"_ the following meaning: IF you **change state of object1** which is in both lists (and it is on both lists because the 2nd list is a shallow copy of the 1st list) - it would change also list2 because object1 is in both

Comment: What @Amin said worked, I had to create a deep copy so that both objects don't have the same reference. It's manual loops & Clones which did the trick. Wonder why we cannot create deep copies in a more simpler way.

Comment: @star67 Bottom line is:- new Arraylist<>(myObjectList); is shallow copy , and changes done in **objects which are stored in either list** will reflect in both list . BUT changes done **in list itself** (changes like delete, insert etc objects in list) will Not reflect in other list.

Comment: @Tarun for sure, this does not contradict with my message above =)

Comment: @star Yes, i commented for someone who will read in future, and we were both right therefore i explained...you were saying 1 point and i was saying 2 point